# Getting attribute error on attribute being imported

Tags: python, cerberus

Sorry for all the questions and thank you for the help.

I have the following code that I'm working for school.  I'm trying to import the Cerberus package into my code with "import cerberus" and that works with no problems.  However, when I run the code I get the following message "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Validator'" Looking over the documentation on Cerberus, it appears I'm doing calling the right things with "import cerberus" and "validator = cerberus.Validator()" or "validator = cerberus.Validate()"

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?  I've been bashing my head for weeks on this problem. Thanks for the assistance, it's greatly appreciated.

```
import cerberus

        validator = cerberus.Validator()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You could replace this huge example with just `import cerberus` followed by `validator = cerberus.Validator()`

Comment: Maybe you've installed `django-cerberus` by mistake.